# include vc_redist 2019 c++ as requirement in .net project

Tags: .net, visual-c++, publish, cefsharp

I have an application where one package (cefsharp) has the requirement of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable > 2019.

Unfortunately, VS will not include this requirement when publishing a single file, framework dependent.

When I start the application, it asks nicely to install .net 6 if ot installed yet.
For Visual C++, it does not do that. The application just wont start, no error message or error log. Just a misleading entry in the event viewer.

Is there a way to specify that requirement in the project so that it will ask as well if you want to install it if not present?

Comment: There are also a number of tools/libs that might be helpful, search `vc redist checker github` in google.

Answer (score 1):

You can bin deploy the runtime, they're just a set of dlls. So in theory you should be able to include the dlls in your exe as `Content`.

The following was written in notepad, should give you a rough idea. Will only run under `VS` as `$(DevEnvDir)` is undefined from command line (going from memory here). Add the following to your proj file.

```xml
<Import Project="$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\Auxiliary\Build\Microsoft.VCToolsVersion.default.props"/>

<PropertyGroup> 
    <_VCRedistLocation>$(DevEnvDir)..\..\VC\Redist\MSVC\$(VCToolsRedistVersion)\$(PlatformTarget)\Microsoft.VC142.CRT</_VCRedistLocation>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(_VCRedistLocation)\**\*">
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <PublishState>Included</PublishState>
      <Visible>false</Visible>
      <IncludeInVsix>true</IncludeInVsix>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: If you have problems try hard coding the path to the dlls then refine from there.